# Pressure inside a typical white dwarf

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, dimensional-analysis, order-of-magnitude

Does any one know the order of magnitude of pressure inside a typical white dwarf (better with reference)? Thanks!

I think it should be $m_e^4c^5/h^3$ (may be multiplied by $\pi$), which is $10^{22} \text{Pa}$, but I am not sure. Just want to make sure this is correct. I tried google it but couldn't find it.

Comment: You can do the math: the gravitational pressure must equal the degeneracy pressure of the electron's fermi gas. See e.g. http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node204.html